# Python Web crawling using Scrapy for html page which require form filling

Tags: python, forms, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl this site which first requires me to fill the form and then get to the required page:
http://fcainfoweb.nic.in/PMSver2/Reports/Report_Menu_web.aspx

I have written following code but don't know whats wrong. Please help:

```
import scrapy

class SpidyQuotesViewStateSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'spidyquotes-viewstate'
start_urls = ['http://fcainfoweb.nic.in/PMSver2/Reports/Report_Menu_web.aspx']
download_delay = 1.5

def parse(self, response):
    yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={
            'ctl00_MainContent_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField':response.css('input#ctl00_MainContent_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            '__EVENTTARGET':'ctl00$MainContent$Rbl_Rpt_type$0',
            #'__EVENTARGUMENT':'',
            #'__LASTFOCUS':'',
            #'__VIEWSTATE':response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            #'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':response.css('input#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            #'__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED':response.css('input#__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            #'__EVENTVALIDATION': response.css('input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            'ctl00$MainContent$Ddl_Rpt_type':'Retail',
            'ctl00$MainContent$ddl_Language':'English',
            'ctl00$MainContent$Rbl_Rpt_type':'Price+report',
        },

    callback=self.parse_tags,
    )


def parse_tags(self, response):
     yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={
            'ctl00_MainContent_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField':response.css('input#ctl00_MainContent_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            '__EVENTTARGET':'ctl00$MainContent$Ddl_Rpt_Option0',
            #'__EVENTARGUMENT':'',
            #'__LASTFOCUS':'',
            #'__VIEWSTATE':response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            #'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':response.css('input#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            #'__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED':response.css('input#__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            #'__EVENTVALIDATION': response.css('input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            'ctl00$MainContent$Ddl_Rpt_type':'Retail',
            'ctl00$MainContent$ddl_Language':'English',
            'ctl00$MainContent$Rbl_Rpt_type':'Price+report',
            'ctl00$MainContent$Ddl_Rpt_Option0':'Daily+Prices',
            },
        callback=self.parse_date,
        )

def parse_date(self, response):
    yield scrapy.FormRequest(
        'http://fcainfoweb.nic.in/PMSver2/Reports/Report_Menu_web.aspx',
        formdata={
            #'ctl00_MainContent_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField':response.css('input#ctl00_MainContent_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            '__EVENTTARGET':'',
            #'__EVENTARGUMENT':'',
            #'__LASTFOCUS':'',
            #'__VIEWSTATE':response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            #'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':response.css('input#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            #'__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED':response.css('input#__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            #'__EVENTVALIDATION': response.css('input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').extract_first(),
            'ctl00$MainContent$Ddl_Rpt_type':'Retail',
            'ctl00$MainContent$ddl_Language':'English',
            'ctl00$MainContent$Rbl_Rpt_type':'Price+report',
            'ctl00$MainContent$Ddl_Rpt_Option0':'Daily+Prices',
            'ctl00$MainContent$Txt_FrmDate':'01/02/2017',
            'ctl00$MainContent$btn_getdata1':'Get+Data',
            },
        callback=self.parse_results,
    )

def parse_results(self, response):
    response.css('div.Panel1')
```

Comment: Do you get an error?  What happens that's different then what you expect?  (People are probably not going to run your code to try to figure out what your issue is...  you need to specify the issue)

Comment: ValueError: No <form> element found in <200 http://fcainfoweb.nic.in/PMSver2/Error.htm>

Comment: So, you're looking for a "form" element on the error page...  Maybe explorer why you're fetching the error page instead of the page you intended?

Comment: I am not able to understand, why is it going on error page.

Comment: Look at the error page... it says "Wrong Input or Unauthorised User".  I'm guessing you're feeding it bad data?

Answer (score 0):

You are scraping a .Net website. They use variables like VIEWSTATE and EVENTVALIDATION etc, you must have to send same values along with request.

[image]

Comment: tried the same, still it is getting redirected to error page.The changes that i made in my code is visible in my question now, still no progress.

Comment: Copy each and every thing .... Are you sending any `user-agent` string? You must do that

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you need to specify headers as well.
Check with Google inspector what are current ones or you can quickly grab below.

```
headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Compress': '0',
}
```

Comment: Even this didn't help!!

Comment: Have you ever looked into Inspector? I see there are different headers + Origin and Referer

Answer (score 0):

See below - you need to follow same

[image]

[image]

Comment: even this didn't help.